# Is there any way to add a hadoop pipe job to workflow in GCP

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to add a hadoop pipe job to a workflow template in GCP but no such example is given anywhere. The official documentation from google specifies how to submit a hadoop job but there is no such parameter available to submit a hadoop pipe job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Dataproc Jobs API and Dataproc Workflows does not support Hadoop Pipes directly and there are no plans to add support for Hadoop Pipes in near future.

If it's possible to run Hadoop Pipes job using `hadoop jar` command instead of `hadoop pipes` by specifying Hadoop Pipes main class then you can use regular [Hadoop Dataproc Job](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/hadoop) to run it.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to pass -program parameter to the job_args?

Comment: Program parameters are specified after `--` symbol: `gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop ... -- param1 param2`